# Valgrind for RISCV64

Tags: cross-compiling, valgrind, riscv

I want to cross compile valgrind tool for riscv64.

I am using the github repository [valgrind-riscv64](https://github.com/petrpavlu/valgrind-riscv64) and I ran the following commands:

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/petrpavlu/valgrind-riscv64
$ ./autogenerate.sh
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-
$ ./configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu \
              --host=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu \
              --prefix=/opt/valgrind-riscv64 \
              CFLAGS=-static \
              CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc \
              CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp \
              CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ \
              LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld \
              AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
$ make
```

I obtained the followin error:

```
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
```

My host machine is an x86, Ubuntu 22.00, kernel 5.15

Comment: Did you find any solution @Mirco Mannino? For me it works without static flag.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to open a GitHub issue. Petr Pavlu, who is driving the RISC-V port, may not follow StackOverflow. Unless of course this is a general RISC-V cross-compilation issue. I know that he uses a RISC-V board for his development so it's possible that cross compilation is untested and unsupported. The Valgrind binaries are somewhat unusual in that they do not link to any external library. That could be causing a problem for your toolchain.